# Why doesn't the move constructor get called in this contrived example?

Tags: c++11, rvalue-reference

Shouldn't the un-named return value from GetPerson bind to the move constructor?

**person.hpp**

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H

#include <string>

struct Person {

    Person(std::string name, int age) : name(name), age(age) {
        std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl;
    }

    Person(const Person& rhs) : name(rhs.name), age(rhs.age) {
        std::cout << "copy ctor" <<  std::endl;
    }

    Person(Person&& rhs) : name(std::move(rhs.name)), age(std::move(rhs.age)) {
        std::cout << "move ctor" <<  std::endl;
    }

    ~Person() {
        std::cout << "dtor" << std::endl;
    }

    std::string name;
    int age;
};

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "person.hpp"

Person GetPerson(std::string name, int age) {
    return Person(name, age);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Person p(GetPerson("X", 21));
}
```

I'm using gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) and compiling with:

```
gcc -g -x c++ -lstdc++ -std=c++0x -o main ./main.cpp
```

Is RVO or NRVO the cause?

Comment: If RVO is preventing it, why would you want to not let it do so?

Comment: @John Zwinck: the example is contrived

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RVO kicks in and elides the copy, and constructs `GetPerson("X", 21)` in place in `p`. Neither the copy constructor nor the move constructor needs to be called.

If you want to force a move here, then `std::move(GetPerson("X", 21))` should do the trick, but I'm not sure why you'd want to.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the move constructor is called or not is unimportant.  What's important is that the COPY constructor is NOT called.

If your code relies on the move constructor being called here, it is broken, per `[class.copy]` p31.

Comment: I was going to edit your answer to include the contents of §12.8/31, but good lord that's a lot of text to reformat.